# How to inject environment variables in elastic beanstalk config.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In the link below

http://docs.shippable.com/deploy/aws-elastic-beanstalk/

it seems like environment variables are used in config.yml . How do we achieve that? It seems like official documentation of aws does not have details on using variables inside config.yml.

Any suggestions will be of great help.

I am looking to set something like
default_platform using env variables and not application variables alone.

Comment: I am looking to set something like default_platform and not just application env variables.

Comment: That doesn't belong to ebextension files. This is only relevant to the time of creation of your beanstalk environment. I believe you want a [CloudFormation template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html) to create/setup your beanstalk. You can specify all beanstalk details in the CloudFormation template. It will be used to create and maintain the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you won't find anything in AWS documentation because using environment variables for templating the `config.yml` is a Shippable feature not an AWS feature.

Shippable details how to add extra ENVs (environment variables) in the [documentation you posted](http://docs.shippable.com/deploy/aws-elastic-beanstalk/):

*Which reads (highlighted in bold):*

---

3. Define deploy-eb-basic-params

Description: `deploy-eb-basic-params` is a params resource that defines variables we want to make easily configurable. ***These variables definitions replace the placeholders in the `Dockerrun.aws.json` and `config.yml` files***.

Steps:
Add the following yml block to the `resources` section in your `shippable.yml` file.

```
# shippable.yml
resources:

  - name: deploy-eb-basic-params
    type: params
    version:
      params:
        ENVIRONMENT: "sample"
        PORT: 80
        AWS_EB_ENVIRONMENT_SINGLE: "Sample-env"
        AWS_EB_APPLICATION: "deploy-eb-basic"
        CUSTOM_ENV_HERE: "some value" # <------------ your custom value here.
```

Then you should be able to reference that ENV `CUSTOM_ENV_HERE` in your `config.yml`

```
# config.yml
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: ${AWS_EB_ENVIRONMENT_SINGLE}
environment-defaults:
  ${AWS_EB_ENVIRONMENT_SINGLE}:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: ${AWS_EB_APPLICATION}
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: ${CUSTOM_ENV_HERE} # <------------ you reference ENV here.
  default_region: ${DEPLOYEBBASICCONFIG_POINTER_REGION}
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: Application
```

Best of luck.